# #define Identifier without a token and without #ifdef in C

Tags: c++, token, c-preprocessor

I have a similar code in my C/C++ project and I want to know the use of `#define` here as it is doesn't have a value and also there is no `#ifdef` or `#ifndef` macro to check it as a condition. Simply the identifier is mentioned in the code after which the function executes.

```
#define SDRAM 
#define ROM


SDRAM
int setup()
{
-----
-----
---
}


SDRAM
void sample()
{
-----
-----
----
}
```

I want to have a clear idea of the `#define` used here. Please help me

Comment: It might be used as a notation for the developer, a way to introduce meaningless keywords to express to humans semantics that don't exist in the language itself. It might also be used by a preprocessor (sed, etc.) to replace them with other text before compilation.  (That's a bit unusual considering that this is the purpose of the C preprocessor, but I've seen it done before...)

Answer (score 2):

It might be to allow attributes and specifiers to be added at a later date, i.e. while `int functionname()` might be fine for now, in future or when compiling with another compiler something like `__declspec(boomshakala) int functionname()` might be required. Then, it's just a matter of adjusting the appropriate #define instead of mucking with multiple function declarations (so you could simply change `#define SDRAM` to `#define SDRAM __declspec(boomshakala)` instead of changing the declarations of `setup` and `sample`. It might be also used for attributes that are only required for one compilation, so the #defines can be supplied on the command line for that compilation. Something like this is often done with `dllimport` and `dllexport`, where the attribute required for each declaration depends on whether the dll or the application using a dll is being compiled.

Answer (score 1):

It probably is used as some annotation. Perhaps some tool or script is scanning the C source to use it. Or perhaps it is some legacy thing.

As an example, [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) contains somewhere `#define emit` and `#define slot` but `emit` and `slot` is useful to `moc` (which parses the user-supplied Qt C++ source code).

As an another example `GTY(`...`)` is very [useful](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GTY-Options.html#GTY-Options) inside the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler source code, which contains `#define GTY(X)` to ignore it, because `GTY`  annotations are processed by `gengtype`

Answer (score 1):

I've already seen defines used like this for code generation. For example in the Qt framework those are parsed in a prebuild step to generate reflection code.

Answer (score 0):

`#define`s without any identifier are too common.

1. `#define`ing a constant without any identifier acts as a **flag** to the
   preprocessor.

   ```
   #define SOMETHING
   #ifdef SOMETHING
   //Do something if SOMETHING is defined.
   #else
   //Do something if SOMETHING is not defined.
   #endif
   ```
2. `#define` replaces the original defined constant with the identifier, hence, if you have not defined the identifier, the *replacement is empty*.
3. `#define` without an identifier is also used as a **guard block** in header files, to prevent multiple inclusion of the same header file, by the same compilation unit.

   ```
   //something.h
   #ifndef SOMETHING_H //We have not yet included something.h, hence SOMETHING_H is undefined.
   #define SOMETHING_H //We have defined SOMETHING_H to show that something.h is included.
   //Code
   #endif
   ```

   In your case, the `#define`d constants `SDRAM` and `ROM` would replace to *nothing* when the code is compiled. In simpler words, it would be as if you have deleted the `SDRAM` and `ROM` as they replace to nothing.